# PyCharm - Proper highlighting for mixed Flask and Vue.js code?

Tags: vue.js, pycharm, jinja2

Is there a way to have Flask and Vue.js code highlight properly within PyCharm?

[image]

---

After setting the Python Template Languages option to Jinja2:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are including template code in your javascript.
You should probably use:

    "userIsLoggedIn: current_user.is_authenticated,"

Are you trying to use JSX?

Comment: @swstephe This is a Flask template file, so if I just have "current_user.is_authenticated", my understanding is that Flask would render that string as-is rather than interpreting it. And I'm not familiar with what JSX is.

Comment: Okay, you can set your Python Template Language here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-template-languages.html ... it doesn't list Flask templates, but Jinja would probably be close enough.

Comment: JSX was copied from ReactJS to VueJS, it is an alternative way of writing HTML templates in Javascript: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip; the Flask code now looks normal, but the JavaScript still seems to not be getting handled properly. I'll update with a new picture.